# Find duplicate opportunity with process builder

Tags: process-builder, opportunity, visual-workflow, opportunity-lineitem

I am working on a requirement when a "deal" opportunity is closed, we need to create a "target" opportunity if a target opportunity does not exists in the system (Deal and Target are the record types). If a "target" opportunity already exists in the system with the same set of opportunity products as they were in the deal opportunity, we should not create a duplicate target opportunity. Can someone help? How do I check whether a target opportunity with the same set of opportunity products exist in the system similar to the deal opportunity? I want to do it with process-builder/flow combination as our users are getting migrated to Lightning in the near future and I don't have to do the re-work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its possible without using apex. The best you can write the logic in trigger.

If you still want to go with Process builder then from there you need to call apex and need to write your logic there.

In apex you can use inner query to get Parent and child record and can compare them.

Comment: I think it's *possible* to write such a flow, but you won't find *me* doing it. Apex Code is definitely the easier route to go.

Comment: @sfdcfox agree with you.

Comment: That was my thought as well. I can clone the opportunity with the opportunity products using the flow, but checking for the existing duplicate opportunity with the same set of products doesn't seem to be something that can be done with process builder.